# Prediction of Holt-Winters Forecasting Algorithm fails

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, holtwinters

I try to forecast a timeseries with the Holt-Winters algorithm. The problem is, that the outputs are completely wrong (straight line in this setting).

I use statsmodels implementation and I'm not sure about the 'seasonal_periods' parameter. At first I tried 60*24 because the data has a frequency of one minute and the seasonality is one day. But I stopped the algorithm after a couple minutes because I do not think that the running time should be that high. With the parameter set to 365 (days per year) I get the results shown in the figure below. Even with this slower value the running time was 5-10 minutes. Is this usual for the Holt-Winters algorithm?

Here is my code:

```
model = ExponentialSmoothing(train_forecast_data_df, seasonal='mul', seasonal_periods=365).fit()
pred = model.predict(start=test_forecast_data_df.index.min(), end=test_forecast_data_df.index.max())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 4))
ax.plot(train_forecast_data_df.index, train_forecast_data_df, label='Train')
ax.plot(pred.index, pred, label='Holt-Winters', alpha=0.7, c='r', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(test_forecast_data_df.index, test_forecast_data_df, label='Test', alpha=0.7)

ax.legend(loc='best')
```

and here the results. Blue is the train data, orange the test data and red the prediction.
[image: forecasting of timeseries]

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your plot, you only have a five days worth of data.  If you are looking for a daily seasonality, you would use seasonal_periods= # of samples you have per day.  Which would have been your first guess of the 1440.

My data contains 34951 samples and my code is below (unfortunately, yes, it takes about an hour to run).
m_h = 8760
fit_yvth = ExponentialSmoothing((yv_trainh), seasonal_periods=m_h, trend='add', seasonal='mul', damped=True).fit()
yv_hath = fit_yvth.forecast(len(yv_th))

Another thing you can do is resample the data to have less which processes much quicker.  I had 4 years worth of minute data I was using.  The hourly data takes an hour or so to complete, the daily data takes less than a minute to run.  (reduces the seasonal_periods of my data to m_d = 365 and 1457 samples)

Using: train_h = train.resample('H').mean().bfill()

You can resample smaller chunks if you don't want to go straight to the hour, for example 5 minutes would be resampled as shown below.

train_5m = train.resample('5M').mean().bfill()

[Below is the output after letting the code do it's thing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhQ47.png)